# iPhone App - load View into Another View as soon as app has loaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a rootviewcontroller and a loginviewcontroller. As soon as my app has finished loading up, I would like the rootviewcontroller to load the loginview associated with the loginviewcontroller. This is because the very first screen will be the user login.....

How is this possible?

The application flow should be as follows:

rootViewController -----immediately loads-----> loginviewcontroller -------user logs in--------> taken to mainmenuviewcontroller

The rootviewcontroller contains all the other controllers because it essentially holds global variables that store the results of processes carried out by other objects...

Comment: Hi ucabdro i didn't get ur question correctly. Can you explain it more and give me correct flow of ur application.

Comment: what u want to do? which one come first view and which second?

Comment: do u expect that ur first view is loginviewcontroller afer that when you clicked on the login button you have go to the nex view named rootviewcontroller . right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your overall UI architecture.

Without having much information, given the fact that it is a login view, I would push it as a modal view. Look at this [document for more info](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html).

In short, you can call `presentModalViewController:animated:` on your `rootviewcontroller` and pass it the `loginviewcontroller`. The login view controller will then be shown on top of the root view controller.

```
[rootViewController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
```

You should provide a way for your login view controller then to be dismissed and return control to the root view controller.

Comment: Perfect! Simple and does exactly what I want....is there a way to change the custom animation so it slides from the right instead of from the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use first screen as login view and second one is root view controller then u use code as

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

viewController= [[loginViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[window addSubview:nc.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

}
and then in loginViewController.m file call rootviewcontroller.